# how to put a number in a text box using a button in visual basic application forms

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am trying to make a calculator on visual basic application forms and I have most of the codes sorted. How do I make it so when I press the number button, it puts the number in the text box. It also needs to be able to work so if I pressed 1 then 2 then 3, it appears a 123.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the SelectedText() property of the TextBox to the Text() property of your button.

For example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.SelectedText = Button1.Text
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```

If you make all the buttons fire the same handler, then it becomes:

```
Private Sub AllButtons_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button4.Click, Button5.Click, _
    Button6.Click, Button7.Click, Button8.Click, Button9.Click, Button0.Click

    Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    TextBox1.SelectedText = btn.Text
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub
```